# Airflow Impersonation with 'run_as_user' Not Working

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to get impersonation working without success. I am following the instructions here - https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#impersonation

I launched airflow webserver, scheduler, and worker as sudo running under the 'airflow' user. This user is setup in the sudoers file to allow no password logins.

I created a BashOperator and a PythonOperator with the run_as_user parameter set to an existing user named 'linus' on the server. When I am logged in as 'airflow', I am able to switch users by running *sudo -u linus* without it prompting me for a password.

```
dag = DAG('test_impersonation', default_args=args)

def print_user(**kwargs):
    print('USER:', getpass.getuser())

t1 = BashOperator(task_id='bash_task', 
                  bash_command='touch /home/linus/test.x',
                  run_as_user='linus',
                  dag=dag)

t2 = PythonOperator(task_id='py_task',
                    python_callable='print_user', 
                    run_as_user='linus',
                    dag=dag)
```

I am testing these tasks with the following commands in the terminal:

```
airflow test test_impersonation bash_task 2018-03-30
airflow test test_impersonation py_task 2018-03-30
```

The first command (BashOperator task) fails with a permission denied error telling me it's still running as the 'airflow' user.

The second command (PythonOperator task) prints the following:

```
USER: airflow
```

I expect this to print *USER: linus*

Is there anything I am missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly certain, but it looks like the `sudo -u` prepend is applied in a `task_runner`, which is setup by the executor, and probably runs the cli run command; while the cli `test` command only calls run on the `task_instance` in test mode, and this doesn't prepend the `sudo -u`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to get it to work using 'airflow trigger_dag' or by running from the UI.In addition to this, I had to move the airflow home directory out of the 'airflow' user directory and into /etc/airflow.

Comment: We have tried doing the same however run as user doesn't work, please guide some detail steps if possible

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and seems that `os.getlogin()` in a `TaskFunction()` of dag.py module returns wrong information! I have similar code, and I was confused by this issue. However in reality the function's code works under proper `run_as_user` id. I've figured that out by proper folder access permissions, accessible environment vars, and it also created some folders, the owner of which was the specified user, and not the airflow user! (which is still reported by s.getlogin() by the way, just rechecked).

So please check user's id in another way, like accessing folders which have exclusive access and/or create some folders!

Update: Use `getpass.getuser()` and be surprised by different result!
As per os.getlogin() doc:

> "os.getlogin() Returns the name of the user logged in on the **controlling terminal** of
> the process... Recommend using getpass.getuser() ... which uses the
> environment variables LOGNAME or USERNAME to find out who the user is...

my test returns:

```
[svc.airflow]$> sudo -u myusername test.py
  ...  os.getlogin=svc.airflow, getpass.getuser=myusername
```