# Airflow: How to download file from Linux to Windows via smbclient

Tags: python, airflow, samba, smb

I have a DAG that imports data from a source to a server. From there, I am looking to download that file from the server to the Windows network. I would like to keep this part in Airflow for automation purposes. Does anyone know how to do this in Airflow? I am not sure whether to use the os package, the shutil package, or maybe there is a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying you're looking for a way to get files from a cloud server to a windows shared drive or onto a computer in the windows network, these are some options I've seen used:

1. Use a service like google drive, dropbox, box, or s3 to simulate a synced folder on the cloud machine and a machine in the windows network.
2. Call a bash command to SCP the files to the windows server or a worker in the network.  This could work in the opposite direction too.
3. Add the files to a git repository and have a worker in the windows network sync the repository to a shared location.  This option is only good in very specific cases. It has the benefit that you can track changes and restore old states (if the data is in CSV or another text format), but it's not great for large files or binary files.
4. Use rsync to transfer the files to a worker in the windows network which has the shared location mounted and move the files to the synced dir with python or bash.
5. Mount the network drive to the server and use python or bash to move the files there.

All of these should be possible with Airflow by either using python (`shutil`) or a bash script to transfer the files to the right directory for some other process to pick up or by calling a bash sub-process to perform the direct transfer by SCP or commit the data via git.  You will have to find out what's possible with your firewall and network settings.  Some of these would require coordinating tasks on the windows side (the git option for example would require some kind of cron job or task scheduler to pull the repository to keep the files up to date).

Comment: Thank you, @chet-the-wizard. I may be thinking too hard, but, if I just used a Python operator with a Samba hook, could I just add some os or shutil commands within the Samba Hook function to move the file? For example:
def file_transfer_to_windows():
     samba = SambaClient( 'login credentials')
     os.popen('path/to/file/in/server path/to/desired/folder/in/windows')

task = PythonOperator(
     'pass the above function through and other args')

Would that work? Or am I thinking of the connection incorrectly?

Comment: I haven't used samba.  There are a lot of ways to skin this cat though, so that's not to say it's not a good option.  Google turned up [this possibly useful code tidbit](https://pypi.org/project/PySmbClient/) to roll into you PythonOperator

Comment: Samba hook would enable a smb connection. Thank you for looking that up. This seems like it is pulling a file from the Windows network, though... Am I incorrect?

Comment: Oh, right, you're trying to go the other direction.  My bad.

Comment: That is fine. I also determined that the Samba Client will not work... at least from what I have tried.  I am thinking about mounting the network drives or possibly using RYSNC via Bash Operator. I think RSYNC would be only a few commands and would work well. I would have liked to use SMB, but, there could be something else out there. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi, @Chet-the-wizard. I thought I would follow up. Mounting the network drive seems to be the best strategy, although, this can only be down with a 'sudo' command. I am trying to use Airflow and would like to make this automated. Do you have any ideas on how to call a 'sudo' command with a BashOperator without having to enter the root password? Thank you.

Comment: @Gess123 I don't have experience with that, but it seems like there is a `run_as_user` option in the bash operator which you could set to root?  Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580187/airflow-impersonation-with-run-as-user-not-working) can help?

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly what I was looking for. The largest concern was leaving something mounted for an extended period of time. This enables me to mount and then unmount in the same DAG. Thank you.